# Entity framework core insert without changetracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a big codebase and unfortunately I cannot reproduce it with a small code example, but I sort of do this:

```
    db.Persons.Add(new Person() {Name = "Foo"});
    await db.SaveChangesAsync()
    await db.Persons.FromSql("truncate table Persons;select top 0 * from Persons").ToListAsync();
    db.Persons.Add(new Person() {Name = "Bar"});
    await db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

And end up with this error on last savechanges:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
> 'InstructionLineAllocationDto' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

I am aware that the truncate is a little non-standard. The Id field that is in the error is an Identity field in database I don't really care about.

I can't find any places explaining how to implement staging tables where you truncate often and insert a bunch and this code also wouldn't be a problem if it ran once per truncate (but this is a listener that always is active)

So all answers that runs permanently and insert a lot and truncate sometimes, but always is active is interesting.

But my most specific question is how I do this without any kind of change tracking

Code is EntityFrameworkCore SqlServer 2.0.0

Comment: why the select top 0 ?

Comment: You could either check and untrack all entities, or reload your dbcontext entirely after your truncate.

Comment: @Pac0 the code only have access to SQL calls via the DbSet. And since it has to be somethng that generates a real Entity then select 0 gives the correct properties for an empty element, and I use the truncate sideeffect to truncate the database table

Comment: mmm without having access to dbContext I don't know how to detach entties.
And as far as I remember, you probably cannot use "`AsNoTracking()`" on an Add.
Could you try do a "`SaveChanges()`" just after ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure exactly what is going on, but it looks like Id is maintained with some loop of a minus-number. As *Pac0* wrote then solution is to detach. So my code ended up being in the `DbContext`

```
    var changedEntriesCopy = _dbEntities.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                    e.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                    e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        .ToList();

    await _dbEntities.SaveChangesAsync();

    foreach (var entry in changedEntriesCopy)
        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
```

The weird part is that `SaveChangesAsync` of course also does the detach, `changedEntriesCopy` consist of 0 entries if code is run after the Save. But with this code the problem is solved.

There is some kind of Entity Framework magic I don't understand.

Comment: Does not weird, because SaveChanges *does not* detaches, just marks the state as not changed.